# How to HitTest Objects in Array Randomly and not in Order.

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Hey everyone so I have Movie Clips that are placed on the stage from the Library. I give all of them instance names and add them to an array like so:

```
       //Initiate arrays
        aZebraArray = [startScreen.zebra_Front, startScreen.zebra_Middle, startScreen.zebra_Back];
```

Then in my Enter_Frame Function I add this code to loop through the array and check the Hit test IF statement like so:

```
private function Round_1Controls():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aZebraArray.length; i++)
        {
            trace(aZebraArray.length);
            var currentZebra = aZebraArray[i];

            if (crosshair.bullet.hitTestObject(currentZebra) && shotGun)
            {
                trace("HIT");

                aZebraArray.splice(i, 1);
                currentZebra.alpha = 0.2
                shotGun = false;
            }else
            {
                shotGun = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this works fine, but the only problem I am having is that I have to Hit Test the first Object in the array. So I have to Hit Test the objects in the array in order of their placement. I can't shoot them randomly. If I dont hit the zebra_Front first then i cant hit any of the others.

Is there a way that I can shoot any of the objects in the array randomly and not by order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your logic. Your code says "even if you don't hit the first zebra, you can't hit any others". Drop the `else { shotgun=false; }` and only set `shotgun` to false after you've checked all the zebras.

```
private function Round_1Controls():void 
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < aZebraArray.length; i++)
    {
        trace(aZebraArray.length);
        var currentZebra = aZebraArray[i];

        if (crosshair.bullet.hitTestObject(currentZebra) && shotGun)
        {
            trace("HIT");

            aZebraArray.splice(i, 1);
            currentZebra.alpha = 0.2
            shotGun = false;
        } // else check next zebra
    }
    shotGun = false; // we've made a shot, after all.
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much @Vesper Once again you have helped me out greatly. I thought it was a problem with the Array. Thanks again man this worked perfect

Answer (score -1):

You have taken variable Boolean  "shotGun" and taken false after one hit and in if condition you have checked if it's true then hit condition apply. Please true this variable when you  hit the gun.

Comment: You could perhaps post the code as an answer which would be more useful